# Cocoa NSPopUpButtonCell not displaying selected value

Tags: swift, cocoa, nstableview, cocoa-bindings, nspopupbuttoncell

**Background**

I have an NSTableView with 3 columns, one of them has an NSPopUpButtonCell.

I have been unsuccessful at using data bindings to populate the cell data, as such I am now trying a new approach by setting values programmatically with addItemsWithTitles.

While this approach has worked to load the values, it is failing to display the default selected (I'm okay with index 0 of my array) and it is also failing to display any item I select in the popup.

**Bindings Issue**

The documentations suggest using bindings and provide an example using Core Data to load relational data in the popup. Although my app is set up differently, I still attempted to use an Array Controller but this would not populate the data in the popUpButtoncell.

My data structure is a simple class object, no core data, and it looks like this.

```
class Display: NSObject {
    var name: String
    var resolution: String
    var availableResolutions: [String]
}
```

I would like to use the availableResolutions array to populate the dropdown.

Each row in my table represents an instance of the Display object. I want the NSPopUpButtonCell to display the items in that particular Display's list of availableResolutions. I'm not sure if it's even possible to have a dynamic list for each Display row.

**What I've tried**

I created an IBOutlet for my NSPopUpButtonCell and I'm referencing it in objectValueForTableColumn and setObjectValue. I add the array of availableResultions inside of objectValueForTableColumn.

```
@IBOutlet weak var popUpCell: NSPopUpButtonCell!

func numberOfRowsInTableView(tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
    return self.displays.count
}

func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, objectValueForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> AnyObject? {
    let display = displays[row]

    if tableColumn!.identifier == "displayCell" {
        return display.name
    }
    else if tableColumn!.identifier == "resolutionCell" {
        return display.resolution
    }
    else {
        self.popUpCell.addItemsWithTitles(display.availableResolutions!)
        return display.availableResolutions
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, setObjectValue object: AnyObject?, forTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) {

    if tableColumn!.identifier == "displayCell" {
        displays[row].name = object as! String
    }
    else if tableColumn!.identifier == "resolutionCell" {
        object as! String
    }
    else {
        let index = object as! Int
        if index >= 0 {
            self.popUpCell.selectItemAtIndex(index)
            self.popUpCell.synchronizeTitleAndSelectedItem()
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure that objectValueForTableColumn and setObjectValue are called? Aren't these for cell-based tableviews? You most likely have a view-based table view.

Comment: The Content Mode is setup for Cell Based. I can confirm objectValueForTableColumn is called as the data for other columns is in fact populated. Also, setObjectValue is called and works if I modify any of the data in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With bindings:

Bind `Selected Value` of the column to `arrangedObjects`, `resolution`.

Bind `Content Values` of the column to the same array controller, `arrangedObjects`, `availableResolutions`.

Without bindings:

The datasource methods `tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:` and `tableView:setObjectValue:forTableColumn:row:` deal with the selected item. The delegate method `tableView:dataCellForTableColumn:row:` deals with the items.

```
func numberOfRowsInTableView(tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
    return self.displays.count
}

func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, objectValueForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> AnyObject? {
    let display = displays[row]
    if tableColumn!.identifier == "displayCell" {
        return display.name
    }
    else if tableColumn!.identifier == "resolutionCell" {
        return display.availableResolutions.indexOf(display.resolution)
    }
    return nil
}

func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, setObjectValue object: AnyObject?, forTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) {
    let display = displays[row]
    if tableColumn!.identifier == "displayCell" {
        display.name = object as! String
    }
    else if tableColumn!.identifier == "resolutionCell" {
        display.resolution = display.availableResolutions[object as! Int]
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, dataCellForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSCell? {
    if let cell = tableColumn?.dataCellForRow(row) as? NSCell {
        if tableColumn!.identifier == "resolutionCell" {
            if let popupButtonCell = cell as? NSPopUpButtonCell {
                popupButtonCell.removeAllItems()
                popupButtonCell.addItemsWithTitles(displays[row].availableResolutions)
            }
        }
        return cell
    }
    return nil
}
```

p.s. I'm not familiar with Swift.

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction. I needed to return the indexOf in objectValueForTableColumn. First I check if display.availableResolutions.indexOf(display.resolution) is nil. If it is then I return the first item in the list, otherwise I return the above. Thank you!